# Apple watch keep app active by few seconds

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

When application on appleWatch go to background app suspended, I know that. But in appStore some applications are active by few seconds after passing into suspend mode and  continues to transmit data (probably use helthKit and workout). How can I keep the application active for a few seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the 2015 WWDC video "[WatchKit Tips and Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/228/?time=345)". They go over how to use GCD's dispatch_semaphore to ask the system for extra time when the app may go into the background. Their example is with an async network request, but the same principle applies to any processing or request you are making.

Note that the amount of time you get is small - you can only get about 30 seconds of background processing time before you are suspended.